# Where and how is the term used "wrapper" used in programming, and what does it help to do?

Tags: oop, terminology

I have come across software developers using the term of creating *wrappers* of other classes or APIs or even some code. This is a term used by experienced software programmers.

What do they mean by it?

E.g. we have two types of array sorting techniques; let's create a wrapper for them.

The above is a very simple example.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

The term 'wrapper' gets thrown around a lot. Generally its used to describe a class which contains an instance of another class, but which does not directly expose that instance. The wrapper's main purpose is to provide a 'different' way to use wrapped object (perhaps the wrapper provides a simpler interface, or adds some functionality).

The word 'wrapper' can also be used when describing classic design patterns.

Wrapping an object to provide a simplified interface to it is often described as the 'Facade' pattern. The wrapper is the facade.

Sometimes you may have a class which would suit a specific interface, but you can't change the code for it to make it conform to that interface. You can create a wrapper for that class which implements the interface, but which directs most of the calls to the wrapped object. This is the 'Adapter' pattern. The wrapper is the adapter.

The instance you describe, where you have two classes which can do array sorting using different algorithms sounds like the 'Strategy' pattern, where you provide a way to perform an operation on some object, but the algorithm used for that operation may be different depending upon the structure of that object.

For example, one of your sort algorithms may be great for arrays of length less than 100, but then performance might be an issue for it. The other algorithm might be good for bigger arrays. You can create a 'wrapper' for the two algorithms which supports the sort operation but decides which algorithm to use based on the array length.

The vast majority of wrappers exist to hide some sort of complexity.

Comment: In python there is the xdress package https://github.com/xdress/xdress . It says it is a wrapper generator. In this context, what does that mean? Does it create an executable in C (which would indeed provide a 'different' (in C) way to use wrapped object (in Python), or am I getting confused?

Answer (score 103):

## Simple Explanation by Analogy

### Example 1: An Ipad "wraps" an Iphone

[image: An iphone is the only thing inside an Ipad. The Ipad literally wraps the Iphone. Except you can't make calls with an Ipad because the ability to make phone calls have not been "exposed". Apple want you to buy x2 products not just one :P]

The Ipad is basically a large Iphone.....it's basically an Iphone but with a different exterior (larger screen). i.e. the Ipad has a different "wrapper".

It's literally the same thing with "objects".

**"Wrappers may expose different features than the underlying object"** ......okay, but what does this mean?

Sometimes the wrapper might limit the things you can access inside. For example, the ipad may limit your ability to make phone calls, even though the Iphone buried within it, has that capability.

### Example 2: Automatic car acting as a wrapper to a manual car

Think of an automatic car, and a manual car.

In an automatic car, there is an engineering mechanism which automatically changes the gears for you, but fundamentally, under the surface, the car is still a manual car.

In other words, the automatic features of the car "wraps" the manual functionality of the car.

If you wanted to manually change the gears by yourself in an automatic car - you simply can't do it. The ability to change gears "is not exposed" in the automatic car. But it is exposed in a manual car. Granted the analogy is a little strained, but I hope you see what I'm getting at.

#### But what is the purpose of a wrapper?

You'd write a wrapping class if you wanted to simplify things. Leave all the complicated bits inside the wrapper, ensuring that those complicated bits are not 'exposed'.

#### Examples - wrappers used in code

1. **[Pysch:](https://github.com/ruby/psych)** It's a ruby wrapper around libyaml, which I believe is written in C. If you wanted to use a libyaml, but with ruby, what are your options? Pysch allows you to write in Ruby, while getting all the benefits of libyaml underneath. It "wraps" libyaml.
2. **.net wrappers:** For example, you could have a .net wrapper, which underneath, makes COM calls. If you didn't have a wrapper, then you'd be forced to make those COM calls yourself. Luckily with the wrapper, you'd just make the calls to the .net wrapping code - which would in turn make those COM calls. And that should hopefully simplify things for you. The AutoCAD .net API is the perfect example. It is a glorified wrapper for the ObjectARX API.

Answer (score 17):

It's just that you write some easy to use code to hide the complexities of the code underneath. It's especially useful when you need to call some low level API from a higher level language and you want to keep all the "ugly" code hidden away.

Edit: You can find more about it in these two wiki articles: [library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_library) and [function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function)

Answer (score 6):

A Wrapper is some code that is created to internally call some API without changing the actual API.

An Example of this is Facebook's release of their *Facebook C# SDK*. The SDK is actually a wrapper since it only lets you call its underlying platform without giving you specific methods and classes. On the other hand, *Facebook Developer Toolkit* is its full API.

Comment: I need to write a C# program that creates a script file (the scripting language is specific to a hardware device and is called `CoraScript`). There are about 50 or so commands in CoraScript e.g., one that connects to a device, one that send files out to that device, tells it to execute an application in its Flash memory etc. Instead of hand-coding a CoraScript, I'd like to create a C# library that'll generate such a script. Would this C# library be called a `wrapper library` for CoraScript scripting language?

Comment: The command-line-interpreter for that scripting language is a console application. While that application runs, it takes CoraScript commands, executes them, and returns that command's output (e.g., the `Connect localhost` CoraScript command would return the string `+connect,"coralib3.dll version 1,8,11"` to indicate that the command had executed successfully).

Answer (score 3):

Wrapper function, a function whose main purpose is to call a second function

Answer (score 2):

There are many examples of "wrappers" and the term is sometimes used interchangeably. Following are a couple examples that come to mind:

**DLL Wrapper**

In the past I have created a COM wrapper around a .NET DLL in order to use the advanced features of .NET in older applications which understand COM but do not understand .NET.

**Object Wrapper (Java)**

In Java, there is a class provided in the `java.lang` package to provide object methods for the eight primitive types. All of the primitive wrapper classes in Java are immutable. So `Wrapper` classes are used to represent primitive values when an `Object` is required.

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to add some more functionalities to your code but you cannot change the code. That's where wrapper helps. You can use a wrapper to get the output without changing the original code.

Answer (score 0):

A practical example of using a wrapper at the system architecture level is that you have a program on your server that do certain processes, and you develop a wrapper through which provides the processing capabilities of that program in the form of several web services. Here, in addition to presenting interfaces to access the capabilities of the program on the web, the wrapper can also provides some default values / safe inputs for it.